# I can't find otool on my jailbroken iPod

Tags: ipod, jailbreak, development

From what I understand is that when you change your settings in Cydia to developer you should be able to access extra utilities. Otool being on of them.

However, when I attempt to use otool it tells me that the command isn't found. So I look in my bin file and can't find it there. (i'm attempting to use it via ssh from my computer)

Can anyone offer suggestions on where to find the tool for my ipod?

Answer (score 6):

When you change your settings to Developer in Cydia, what you are actually doing is changing the package list filter. This means that certain packages will only be shown as **available to download and install** in the package list according to which filter you select.

***Having set your filter settings to 'Developer' you'll then need to find and install the package you want.***

**otool is included in the package called: BigBoss Recommended Tools**

Comment: Hi, I jailbroke my iOS 7.1.2 using Pangu. I have Cydia 1.1.23 and have installed BigBoss Recommended Tools 1.3.2 as suggested above. However, I am still unable to find otool on it. I checked in /usr/bin as well and could not find otool there either. Also, although there is class-dump but I would like to use class-dump-z. So any pointers on how can I get that on my jailbroken device ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a mac, you could use otool there on iOS binaries, should work with ARM-based code as well. (otool is installed with Xcode's command-line tools.)

Update: Based on this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/202656/8699) to a related question, you can now find `otool` in the "Darwin CC Tools" package from the Cydia/Telesphoreo repository. Doesn't seem to be in "BigBoss Recommended Tools" package anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just install BigBoss Recommended Tools, oTool is included there.