# Otool on JailBroken device

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I jailbroke my iOS device running iOS 7.1.2 using Pangu. I have Cydia 1.1.23 and have installed "BigBoss Recommended Tools 1.3.2" as suggested here: [otool BigBoss Recommended Tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/i-cant-find-otool-on-my-jailbroken-ipod)

However, I am still unable to find otool on it. I checked in `/usr/bin` as well and could not find otool there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove LD64 and then install the Darwin CC tools (2nd one had otool).

Comment: The "2nd one" being the package from the Cydia/Telesphoreo repository.